# Is there a simple way to reverse this jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, function, animation, jquery-animate, wordpress-theming

I'm new to animating with jQuery (Also I'm using WordPress). I'm afraid that creating a bunch of animation functions will really make the site heavy and bog everything down. I'd like to keep the amount of functions as minimal as possible and so I'd really like to know what is the least taxing way to reverse this set of functions? Is it even possible without re-writing the animations entirely? I just need to run them in the opposite direction on scroll.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#sprite").animate({bottom: '0px'}, 400, 'linear', function () {
        $("#sprite").css({
            'background-image': 'url(http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/media/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
            'height': '50px',
            'width': '90px',
            'left': '300px',
            'bottom': '80px'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#sprite").css({
                'background-image': 'url(http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/media/images/test-sprite.png)',
                'height': '120px',
                'width': '96px'
            });
        }, 80);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the original css in a variable, then set the css back to the original.

```
var orgCss = $("#sprite").css();
//do stuff here...

$("#sprite").css(orgCss);
```

Comment: I like this idea. I didn't realize I could do that. I'll give it a try.